# Javascript - if string contains and replace

Tags: javascript, html

I must be making a simple mistake or misunderstanding of the function. As you can see below, I am trying to replace '-' to '/' when user type '-'. I am trying to do this onkey so, if the user types in say 12-12-12. it will replace all 3 dashed right away ex: user enters like 12- function turns to 12/ right away.

what i am i doing wrong here.

```js
function onkey(){
var user_input = document.getElementById('date_val').value;
// if(user_input.includes("-")){
// console.log("detects")
// user_input.replace(/-/g, "/");
// }
user_input.includes("-")? console.log("detects") && user_input.replace(/-/g, "/"):user_input;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>


</head>

<body>
date :<input type="text" id="date_val"  onkeyup="onkey()"> 
  

  <script src="./js/test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the result from the function **[`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)**.

> Adopt the function **[`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)** to bind events to your elements.

```js
document.getElementById('date_val').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/-/g, "/");
});
```

```html
Date :<input type="text" id="date_val">
```

This is an alternative using the event `input` to capture every change in that input field.

> This way, you will provide a better user experience and will be handled every change like a drag, drop and text paste as well.  Look how while you're writing the replacement is not visible.

```js
document.getElementById('date_val').addEventListener('input', function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/-/g, "/");
});
```

```html
Date :<input type="text" placeholder="Paste, Drag & Drop text" id="date_val">
```

Answer (score 1):

String.replace returns a *new* string. In order to change the value, you would need to `document.getElementById('date_val').value = user_input.replace(/-/g, "/");`

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

> The replace() method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement. The pattern can be a string or a RegExp, and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called for each match.

You have to reset the value of the element:

```js
function onkey(){
  var user_input = document.getElementById('date_val').value;
  document.getElementById('date_val').value =  user_input.replace(/-/g, "/");
}
```

```html
date :<input type="text" id="date_val"  onkeyup="onkey()">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the value of the element `dateElement.value = user_input.replace(/-/gi, "/");`

Also, `.replace` does not modify the string.  It returns a new string, so your `user_input` will not have changed.

I also clean up the code a bit more to be a bit more readable and refactored.

You also don't need the `include` check, as this has to go through the entire string anyway.  You might as well just replace every time, since it's probably pretty close to the same overhead.

```js
function onkey(){
    var dateElement = document.getElementById('date_val');
    
    dateElement.value = dateElement.value.replace(/-/g, "/");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    date :<input type="text" id="date_val"  onkeyup="onkey()"> 
</body>

<script src="./js/test.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you read a value from input, you get a new instance of the string, you need to assign it back to the input.

```js
function onkey() {
  const input = document.getElementById('date_val');
  const user_input = input.value;
  const newValue = user_input.includes("-") ? user_input.replace(/-/g, "/") : user_input;
  console.log(newValue);
  input.value = newValue;
}
```

```html
date :<input type="text" id="date_val" onkeyup="onkey()">
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('date_val').value = user_input.replace(/-/g, "/");